# Group by one column and Show all results from another column

Tags: php, mysql

Hi guys I am trying solve this , I can't find a solution.

I have 2 columns, am trying to make a select and group by first column and display all records from the second column. My table is:

```
RegNo   Name
C117    Mariya Mathew
C117    Baino Baby
C117    Mathews Reji
C120    Nithin Abraham
C120    Vipin Saji
C120    Veetu Thomman
```

so my results are supposed to be:

```
C117  Mariya Mathew, Baino Baby, Mathews Reji
C120  Nithin Abraham, Vipin Saji, Veetu Thomman
```

Kindly help me...Thanks in Advance...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use GROUP_CONCAT

```
SELECT RegNo, GROUP_CONCAT(Name SEPARATOR ', ') Names
FROM MyTable
GROUP BY RegNo
```

Comment: Thank you So much Mr. Barmar. Quick response :)