# In MySQL How do I SELECT all ids from rows with a similar value

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I want to pull all the unique IDs for particular rows with the same username and then display each result as a row.

For example...

Here's my table:

```
+----+------+
| id | name |
+----+------+
| 1  | Joe  |
| 2  | Amy  |
| 3  | Joe  |
| 4  | Amy  |
| 5  | Joe  |
| 6  | Amy  |
+----+------+
```

Here's the result I want:

```
+------+-------+
| name | ids   |
+------+-------+
| Joe  | 1,3,5 |
| Amy  | 2,4,6 |
+------+-------+
```

How do I pull this result in MySQL?

Comment: Might be able to do something like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19558443/comma-separated-string-of-selected-values-in-mysql and include a way to do a group by name?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Group by one column and Show all results from another column](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17716854/group-by-one-column-and-show-all-results-from-another-column)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use a [`GROUP_CONCAT()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) with `DISTINCT` clause to aggregate unique ids for a particular name:

```
SELECT name, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT id SEPARATOR ',') AS ids
FROM yourtable
GROUP BY name
```

To review the usage of it also see [MySQL group_concat with select inside select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35614678/mysql-group-concat-with-select-inside-select/35614847#35614847).

Comment: This is perfect. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [group_concat](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) for that:

```
SELECT   name, GROUP_CONCAT(id) AS ids
FROM     table
GROUP BY name
```

You can also specify a separator, but the one by default is the comma.

You can also specify `DISTINCT`, but since *id* is unique, there is no reason to this: all it will do is slow down the query.

Here is [SQL fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ccb282/2) producing the output as desired:

```
+------+-------+
| name | ids   |
+------+-------+
| Joe  | 1,3,5 |
| Amy  | 2,4,6 |
+------+-------+
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a what the [`group_concat`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) operator is designed for:

```
SELECT   name, GROUP_CONCAT(id) AS ids
FROM     mytable
GROUP BY name
```